# Shared WebDriver becomes null on second scenario using PicoContainer

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, picocontainer

I have used the accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573676/sharing-same-selenium-webdriver-between-step-definition-files) and came up with the following code:

**Referenced Libraries:**

[image: pico_ref_libs]

**Feature:**

```
Feature: FeatureA

  Scenario: ScenarioA
    Given 
    When 
    Then

  Scenario: ScenarioB
    Given 
    When 
    Then
```

**BaseStep:**

```
public class BaseStep {
    protected WebDriver driver = null;
    private static boolean isInitialized = false;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        if (!isInitialized) {
            driver = SeleniumUtil.getWebDriver(ConfigUtil.readKey("browser"));
            isInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**StepA:**

```
public class StepA {
    private BaseStep baseStep = null;
    private WebDriver driver = null;

    // PicoContainer injects BaseStep class
    public StepA(BaseStep baseStep) {
        this.baseStep = baseStep;
    }

    @Given("^I am at the Login page$")
    public void givenIAmAtTheLoginPage() throws Exception {
        driver = baseStep.driver;
        driver.get(ConfigUtil.readKey("base_url"));
    }

    @When
    @When
    @Then
    @Then

}
```

However, the driver "dies" after `tearDown()` of ScenarioA and becomes null on Given step of ScenarioB (both scenarios use the same Given). I am not using Maven.

Comment: The solution is not using a TearDown so that next Step can have the driver. Why are you using the?

Comment: Using the? Commenting out the `tearDown()` method had the same results. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of this line:

```
private static boolean isInitialized = false;
```

For each scenario, cucumber creates a new instance for every step file involved. Hence, the `driver` in `BaseStep` is always null when a scenario starts.

The static `isInitialized` boolean is not part of an instance, it's bound to the class it lives in and it's alive until the JVM shuts down. The first scenario sets it to `true`, meaning that when the second scenario starts it's still `true` and it does not reinitialize the driver in the `setUp()` method.

You probably want to make `driver` static to share the same instance with both scenarios.

Comment: You are correct. I removed the boolean and the if-check. Accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

From Luciano's answer, this is what I ended up with:

**Features:**

```
Feature: FeatureA

  Scenario: ScenarioA
    Given I am at the Login page
    When 
    Then

  Scenario: ScenarioB
    Given I am at the Login page
    When 
    Then


Feature: FeatureB

  Scenario: ScenarioC
    Given I am at the Login page
    When 
    Then
```

**BaseStep:**

```
public class BaseStep {
    protected WebDriver driver = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = SeleniumUtil.getWebDriver(ConfigUtil.readKey("browser"));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Steps:**

```
public class FeatureAStep {
    private WebDriver driver = null;

    // PicoContainer injects BaseStep class
    public FeatureAStep(BaseStep baseStep) {
        this.driver = baseStep.driver;
    }

    @Given("^I am at the Login page$")
    public void givenIAmAtTheLoginPage() throws Exception {
        driver.get(ConfigUtil.readKey("base_url"));
    }

  @When
  @When
  @Then
  @Then
}


public class FeatureBStep {
    private WebDriver driver = null;

    // PicoContainer injects BaseStep class
    public FeatureBStep(BaseStep baseStep) {
        this.driver = baseStep.driver;
    }

  @When
  @Then
}
```

I have 2 Feature files and 2 Step Definition classes. ScenarioC shares the same Given from Scenarios A and B that is defined in FeatureAStep. When and Then of ScenarioC is defined in FeatureBStep. I did not make the WebDriver static in BaseStep using PicoContainer. Both Feature files executed successfully.

---

**Related Reading:**

- [Cucumber: You're not allowed to extend classes that define step
  definitions or
  hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985002/cucumber-youre-not-allowed-to-extend-classes-that-define-step-definitions-or-h)
- [Dependency Injection-Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/java-di)
- [Sharing selenium Webdriver instance using PicoContainer in
  Cucumber](http://www.softpost.org/cucumber/sharing-selenium-webdriver-instance-using-picocontainer/)